React Native ScrollView adds extra space on top - outside the scrollview
I have a react native application which is having a scrrollview and when I scroll back to top there is an extra space added outside of the scrollview container. I have added a view to show the issue I'm facing. The issue is there only on Android Simulator.
RN version: - 0.75.2
Node version - 20.16.0
Simulator - Pixel 3A XL(API 34)
Here is the code for reference
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: '#000'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 24, lineHeight: 32, color: '#FFF'}}>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
            veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
            voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
            officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
            nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum.
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

Here is the video:
enter image description here
I am expecting it to not add the extra space on top


Adjust ScrollView styles:
Try setting padding: 0 and margin: 0 on the ScrollView component:
Use android:scrollbarStyle:
Add the following to your Android styles.xml file (usually located at android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml):
XML
Disable overScrollMode:
Add overScrollMode="never" to your ScrollView component:
Check for conflicting styles:
Verify that no other styles or layouts are applying padding or margin to the ScrollView or its parent components.
If none of these solutions resolve the issue, please provide more code context or clarify the exact React Native version you're using. This will help me provide more targeted assistance.
Also, you can try setting stickyHeaderIndices to an empty array [] if you have any sticky headers in your ScrollView.


Hi Travour, overScrollMode="never" seems to have solved my problem but the scroll is not as smooth as earlier. I'll still accept the answer as it has solved the problem.
